# pngのファイルサイズを一定以下にする方法

Tags: ubuntu, png

Ubuntuを使っています。
pngの画像ファイル容量をある一定以下にしたいと思っています(例：200KB以下)
圧縮率で下げる方法は見つかりましたが、ファイル容量を設定して下げる方法はないのでしょうか。

ご存知の方、ご教示いただけると幸いです。

Comment: 参考: 英語版で関連するかもしれない質問 - [ImageMagick: scale PNG image with a maximum file-size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45431366)

Answer (score 2):

PNG は可逆圧縮の画像フォーマットです。質問者さんがおっしゃるように、表現している画像データを変えないのであれば一般の画像に対しては圧縮アルゴリズムの部分で頑張る他ありません。JPEG のような非可逆圧縮の画像フォーマットではロスを増やすという犠牲を払ってサイズを小さくすることができますが、PNG ではそのようなやり方は少なくともファイルフォーマット上は使えません。

圧縮の可逆性を失ってしまいますが、画像の縦横サイズや色数を弄っても良いのであればそこを小さくすることでファイルサイズも小さくすることは可能です。色数を小さくするための手段としては [pngquant](https://pngquant.org/) などのツールが知られています。

また、もはや PNG の話ではなくなってしまいますが、もしウェブ用にファイルサイズを小さくしたいという意図であれば [WebP](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp) など他のフォーマットが使えないか検討してみるのも手です。